# limits on sprintf precision

Tags: c, printf

I came across this code recently.  It produces strange results (lots of random digits after about the 18th digit.)  I tried to find information on the limits to sprintf but could not find it.  I am trying to figure out if the answer is actually correct or just garbage.  When passed 0.025 (as a double) it prints out:

0.025000000000000001387778780781445675529539585113525390625

```
#define MAX_NUM_STR_LEN 128
void File_WriteNumber(File *fp, double value) {
    char numbuf[MAX_NUM_STR_LEN];
    int sz = sprintf(numbuf, "%.100g", value);
    fwrite (numbuf , sizeof(char), sz, fp);
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: Are you passing `0.25` or `0.025`?

Comment: @MichaelAlbers oops.  Corrected.

Comment: 10e50 same questions on internet. Do some researches yourself before asking. Respect our time. Google should become your best friend

Comment: its actually limits on the precision of double https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: The answer is that (s)printf is behaving properly here. You need to learn about floating point, and the fact that decimal numbers like 0.1 and 0.025 cannot be represented exactly.  Try a number like 0.25 or 0.125, and you shouldn't see any garbage (since those numbers *do* have exact representations in base-2 floating point).

Comment: You were printing `1/40` which is exactly representable in the decimal system but not in a binary system. Consider `1/3` or `1/7` which are not exactly representable in either system. You surely understand the situation in the decimal system, and similar applies to binary. The representations are not finite, or even within the precision available.

Comment: The Wikipedia page on [Double-precision floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) says of the format: *This gives from 15 to 17 significant decimal digits precision.*

Answer (score 4):

Answer is actually correct - not random digits.

---

`double` can typically represent *exactly* about 2<sup>64</sup> different values.

0.025 is not one of them with a [binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) `double`.

The closest `double` is 0.025000000000000001387....
The next closest `double` is 0.024999999999999997918...

`sprintf()` is doing just fine.